# OP's 1:st edit made answers wrong, 2:nd edit added a solution

Tags: discussion, answers, self-answer

I answered a question which initially failed to tell that the solution should be using html/css only.

After some time I noticed my reps. went down and after a check, that very same question were edited saying "I know this can easily be achieved using javascript, or ...".

I asked the OP and he told he edited it and waited a while and then downvoted the 2 answers that he got, as they became wrong after the edit.

I told him you don't change a question making the answers wrong and then downvote without notifying the answerers.

So I deleted my answer (so did the other answerer), did a research and undeleted it with an answer which were not wrong.

Then I told the OP and he removed his downvote, and commented on my new answer and said that a part of it wasn't exactly how he ment and provided me a fiddle with a script doing it in the way he ment.

I removed that part of my answer and told him to add it as a self answer and that I would upvote it.

He said no because he is looking for a html/ccs and will wait for that and at the same time edited his version into his question as a script solution.

The post can be found here: [How to limit element heights to specific values ("stepped") based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218973/how-to-limit-element-heights-to-specific-values-stepped-based-on-content)

As there is only one answer (mine) I don't see any point rolling back both the 2 edits, but I do think the script version should, and be added in another way, so future users can see that there actually is a solution, even if the OP was looking for another.

So should I;

- edit his post making the solution a part of the question as "this is what I got now, but want a html/css only solution ...."
- remove it completely and add it as community wiki, with credits to the OP

If the latter, is there a way to set the OP's signature on the answer or do I just add his "alias" into the answer?

Comment: Some people just can't be helped. I'd move on.

Comment: I am surprised to see such a behaviour (editing the question in a substantial way that invalidates the answers and downvoting them) from a user with more than 1000 rep and that has been a member for 2 years. I'd only expect it from a new user with just 1 rep (apart from the fact that in that case he couldn't downvote).

Comment: Wow. What a jerk.

Comment: If the OP were a low rep newbie acting from ignorance it would be unfortunate, but understandable. But an established SO user ought to know better than to engage in such "chameleon" tactics. His personally down-voting the answer he invalidated just adds insult to injury. At least he _did_ reverse the dv, once you explained the situation, but still...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### What should have happened

The OQA should have realized after reading the first set of answers that he'd forgotten an important requirement that rendered the answers he'd received incorrect. Knowing that he can't move the goalposts after a shot has been made (as it were), OQA should have voted based on the merits of his originally-posted question, given his check mark, and written a *NEW* question including the requirement that the solution use only HTML/CSS. Optionally the OQA could have mentioned this in the original question as a comment and linked to the new question.

### What do we do now?

I propose that the question is rolled back to its original state (without the html/css-only requirement) and the answers are similarly rolled back. A comment should be left explaining why this was done, and hopefully OQA doesn't try to get into an edit war with the community or downvote his frustration. I'd strongly recommend that the OQA still writes up the new question if he wants an answer.

As for OQA's own JS answer, it should be created and added as a community wiki answer to the existing question.

Comment: Is there a way to set the OP's signature on the community wiki answer or do I just add his "alias" into the answer?

Comment: I wouldn't credit the OQA in the community wiki. It's only there to provide another possibility and since he's already declined to make it an answer, I don't think there's anything more that needs to be done. If you'd like I'd give attribution only as a comment on the community wiki answer.

Comment: The proposed action have been taken, though there were another answer to the question but I don't have enough reps to either find nor restore it.

Answer (score 3):

jerk OP speaking. First off: if I offended anyone, which seems to be the case, I want to apologise. That was never my intention, and I'm sorry it felt like this. I feel like I want to tell my point-of-view:

1. I asked a question about limiting elements to a specific height using html/css. I did, as LGSOn stated, **not** include it in my question that I don't want javascript. However, I did only set the [html] and [css] tag to my question. How often have I seen answers downvoted when they used jQuery, but the question was only tagged with javascript. So I thought it was clear what languages an answer should include, in this case html and css, because writing it in javascript is, as I have stated in my edit, something I could do myself.
2. As two answers came along which **did** indeed use javascript, I felt I should put an emphasis on not using javascript also in the question text, not only the tags. The answers therefore were not suited to my question, therefore I downvoted. I would argue they weren't from the start because of the tags I have set, but obviously you feel different. I however removed the downvote after a discussion in the comments with LGSon.

What I probably should have done: instead of giving a downvote, I should have left a comment that this doesn't suit my needs, and I have updated the question. I was under the impression the question was clear from the start (again, tags), but obviously it wasn't, so I just could have cleared up the situation by leaving a comment. I did not, and I'm surprised by the huge waves this has caused. Again, @LGson I'm sorry for any offense given, I hope you can see why I did what I did.

**Edit**:
Finally, I have made a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433476/how-to-limit-element-heights-to-specific-values-stepped-based-on-content).

Comment: I'm not offended (don't think anyone is), this topic is about how to write a question and deal with its answers. "Tagging" as I see it, doesn't limit the answers, just categorize the question, and as javascript is very related to html, an answer using it couldn't possible been seen as wrong. The edit's that were made is not within SO policies and therefore these action were taken. One shouldn't alter a question making its answers wrong and on top of that add a solution into it, and you should know that being a member this long.

Comment: Feel free, and it actually would be great, to both link from the original question and create a new one, with your "html/css only" requirement.

Comment: Just a tip, though it seems like you may have already learned this from this situation: Don't just use tags to restrict a question. Make sure it's _explicit_ in your question. If you make it explicit from the get-go, then an answer that completely ignores your restriction (especially a restriction that's well explained so they can't just say "Well, that's a stupid restriction, you should do this anyway!") can be downvoted and commented on, and you are in the right.

Comment: yes, i will do this in the future. Still amazed by how big this whole things got ;-) anyway, I'll let the question stand as is and ask a new one